# How to open an html page that contains the information from a json file, another page that contains details of only specefic data of the json file

Tags: html, angularjs

Sorry I couldn't put a good title but I hope you will understand my question.
In my html page, I am using AngularJS to show some informations here's my code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in list">
   <td>{{d.nm}}</td>
   <td>{{d.cty}}</td>
   <td>{{d.hse}}</td>
   <td>{{d.yrs}}</td> 
</tr>
```

Now what I want to do in the actual page is to show only the name, link this page to another one that contains the details in order to get cleaner pages.
So here's my plan

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in list">
   <td ng-href="details.html">{{d.nm}}</td>
</tr>
```

and in details.html I want to show only the details about the name I clicked on.
For example if I have:

```
  {
    ["nm": "xxx",
    "cty": "yyy",  
    "hse": "zzz",
    "yrs": 2016
    ],
   ["nm": "aaa",
    "cty": "bbb",  
    "hse": "ccc",
    "yrs": 2014
    ]
}
```

So If I click on xxx in my home page, in details.html I should get only yyy, zzz and 2016 etc...
Is that possible?

EDit

```
app.factory('myapp', ['$http', function($http) {        
function getLists() {
var tab = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];
var list = [];
for(i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
    $http.get(tab[i]) 
    .then(function(res) {
        list.push(res.data);
    });
   }
return list;
}

  return {
  getLists: getLists
 };
 ]);
```

Controller:

```
$scope.list = myapp.getLists();
```

Comment: Do they have common controller or different controller?

Comment: @SyamPillai yes they have the same controller

Comment: checked my answer?

Comment: @SyamPillai I am trying it I just have some problems because in my real code I am parsing different json files

Answer (score 0):

If they are in same controller

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in list">
  <td ng-href="details.html" ng-click="getDetails(d)">{{d.nm}}</td>
</tr>
```

in **Controller** :

```
$scope.getDetails = function(data){
   $scope.selectedData = data;
 }
```

In **details.html** :

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in selectedData">
  <td>{{d.nm}}</td>
  <td>{{d.cty}}</td>
  <td>{{d.hse}}</td>
  <td>{{d.yrs}}</td> 
</tr>
```

And the JSON you provided is not a **valid one**

change that to :

```
[
  {"nm": "xxx",
   "cty": "yyy",  
   "hse": "zzz",
   "yrs": 2016
  },
  {"nm": "aaa",
   "cty": "bbb",  
   "hse": "ccc",
    "yrs": 2014
  }
 }
```

Comment: I am going to edit my question with my factory and controller codes

Comment: I have done in the controller 
$scope.selectedData = myapp.getLists(d);